# Format international currencies

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net application that we are in the process of "globalizing", I have the currentculture and currentUICultre being set to the appropriate values and currencies are displaying as expected using the format currency ie.

```
FormatCurrency(_nPrice)
```

produces

$xxx.xx for en-AU and £xxx.xx for the en-GB, however we need to distinguish the currency of the value is being displayed in, other than the symbol because a lot of currencies use the dollar sign.

For example we need to display US$123.12 for the States or A$123.12 for Australia. Is there an automatic way of doing this like there is for the symbol.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[RegionInfo](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System.Globalization/types/RegionInfo.html)** contains the **[ISOCurrencySymbol](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System.Globalization/types/RegionInfo.html#ISOCurrencySymbol)**. Since you already have the CurrentCulture, You could do the following:

```
string currencySymbol = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.ISOCurrencySymbol;

// currencySymbol equals EUR for France(fr-FR) or any EU country
// returns AUD for en-AU, US for en-US, etc.
```